# Adding MoPub AdView (UIView) over a EAGLView in A Game cause EAGLView touch to be ignored?

Tags: ios, mopub

My touch on AdView doesn't propagate to EAGLView which is beneath current UIView. The touch are observed on UIView's TouchBegan methods.

How can I make this touch propagates to EAGLView beneath UIView?

Any help and suggestions would be very appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way to accomplish above task. We can always access number of views on _window view by following code :

```
viewsInWindow = [[self.view superview] subviews]
```

It gives the number of views on window view in arrays and you can access any view from array with

```
myEAGLView = [viewsInWindow objectAtIndex:0]    // For first and so on for next views.
```

And then accomplish what you needs to do in ur desired view.

Hope this would help someone.